# symfony2 Class sub class of "Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository" is not a valid entity or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, doctrine

```
namespace griffin\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="griffin\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User {

    const STATUS_ACTIVE   = 1;
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_users", type="smallint")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $idUsers;
```

And Repository class like

```
namespace griffin\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function getAdmin()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery('select * from users where users_groups_id = 1')
                ->getResults;
    }
}
```

And when I call it in my controller

```
$results = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('griffin\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository')
    ->getAdmin();

var_dump($results);
```

I got error 
`Class "griffin\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository" sub class of "Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`getRepository()` takes the entity class as first argument:

```
$results = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('griffin\UserBundle\Entity\User')
    ->getAdmin();
```

---

**Note:** It's always a good idea to have a quick look at the [EntityManager](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L734-L761) class itself. If you do, you will see this method signature for `getRepository()`:

```
/**
 * Gets the repository for an entity class.
 *
 * @param string $entityName The name of the entity.
 *
 * @return EntityRepository The repository class.
 */
public function getRepository($entityName)
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this->getDoctrine->getRepository('griffin\UserBundle\Entity\User')` instead. The method getRepository expects the name of the entity you want the repository for, not the repository name itself, since not every entity has to have a custom repository class.

See http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes